# In CoffeeScript, how can I filter out a global array without accidentally declaring it?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm pretty new to CoffeeScript, and I've been [reading this book](http://arcturo.github.io/library/coffeescript/04_idioms.html). There's a section called **Select** that talks about using your typical functional programming `filter` function.  It says you can do it like this:

```
attacks = (attack for attack in attacks when attack is "a")
```

The intent is to filter out all the elements that don't equal "a".  This works fine, as long as `attacks` is declared in the same file.  But, if I've got `attacks` declared in another file, like so:

```
attacks = ["a", "b"]
root = exports ? this
root.attacks = attacks
```

Then the first code gets compiled like this:

```
function() {
    var attack, attacks, _i, _len;
    ...
```

And you'll get an error on the `for` loop saying

> TypeError: attacks is undefined

This is happening, I guess, because CoffeeScript sees something on the left hand side of an `=` it doesn't know about and decides it needs to be declared.

How can I avoid this?

---

Actually, I've already figured out one method.  And that is to modify the first snippet to say this:

```
root.attacks = (attack for attack in attacks when attack is "a")
```

Is this a good solution?

Comment: This doesn't look right `root = exports ? this`? Is that valid Coffeescript syntax? Is that meant to be a half-ternary operator? Or an existencial operator? I don't get it.

Comment: @elclanrs yes.  When I google for how to export a variable, that's what my results show.  Is there a better way?

Comment: I don't know much Coffescript, but just looks wrong for some reason. Are you basically saying this `root = exports || this`?

Comment: @elclanrs I think there's a subtle difference, but that's the spirit of it, yes.  "returns true unless a variable is null or undefined"

Comment: a = a ? b is similar to a = a || b except that a = a || b will assign from the second operand for any a that evaluates to false (which can cause issues when a is 0, for example).  a = a ? b on the other hand only assigns if a isn't null and unfolds to: a = a != null ? a : b;

Comment: @Brandon: according to that same book, it also checks for `undefined`.

Comment: @Brandon: Oh, get it. Haven't used Coffescript much but seems like a good use.

Comment: It skips the undefined check when the lvalue is the same as the first operand because you are assigning to the lvalue so it will either no longer be undefined or it will be explicitly set as undefined.  Which means for root = exports ? this it would, indeed, check undefined.

Comment: I can't see how `root.attacks = (attack for attack in attacks when attack is "a")` would work. If iteration fails, trying to assign its results back doesn't have much effect.

Comment: do you want something like `root.attacks = (attack for attack in attacks when attack is "a") if attacks instanceof Array`?

Comment: @JanDvorak How would iteration fail?  Wouldn't that be an exceptional case?  You can assume that `attacks` is an array.

Comment: @tieTYT if `attacks` is an array, then how can the first snippet fail?

Comment: @JanDvorak If you say `attacks =` then CoffeeScript `var`s the variable `attacks`, shadowing the global variable.  If you say `root.attacks =`, then it doesn't shadow, so it'll iterate over the global `attacks` properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coffeescript will use the global "window" if you explicitly tell it to.  I would be hesitant to start assigning properties directly to window if I were you.  At the very least you could put them all into one object on window like:
`window.globals = window.globals ? {}` then `window.globals.attacks = (attack for attack in attacks when attack is "a")`.  For a more robust solution you could consider something like the following:

```
window['moduleName'] = (->
  someOtherVariableToExpose = 'something'
  # All of your code

  attacks: attacks
  anotherThing: someOtherVariableToExpose)()
```

In javascript this looks like:

```
window['moduleName'] = (function() {
  var someOtherVariableToExpose;
  var attacks;

  someOtherVariableToExpose = 'something';
  attacks = 'whatever your code defined it as';
  return {
    attacks: attacks,
    anotherThing: someOtherVariableToExpose
  };
})();
```

This creates a nice little closure around all of this file's private code and only exposes window['moduleName'].attacks, and window['moduleName'].anotherThing.

If your app will grow large you could look into module dependency libraries such as [requirejs](http://www.requirejs.org) or [browserify](http://browserify.org/)

Edited To make sure the anonymous function was called immediately so the returned object really is all that is exposed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes your solution is a good solution.  Coffeescript will create a local variable for your references if you're not pulling them in from somewhere else explicitly so you need to do that.  If you know that this code is in node or in the browser you can be more explicit and say `window.attacks` or require() the file that contains attacks and grab it that way.  If its intended to be shared then your solution is a good one.

Comment: This is client side js.  Should I prepend `window.` everywhere I refer to `attacks` or just where it's necessary to prevent runtime errors as I did in my solution?

Comment: Yep, if you know it will be client side that's a good way to go.  Or do something like atx=window.attacks right at the start and then refer to atx afterwards to preserve the shorter simpler syntax